# Rails 4 - Why Can't I Redirect After Save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4

I am uploading several images (from `http://localhost:3000/choices/new`), which work fine, however, I am trying to redirect back to: `http://localhost:3000/choices` after it saves.

Here is my controller:

```
#app/controllers/choices_controller.rb
def create
 @choice = Choice.new(choice_params)
 @choice.filename = params[:filename].titleize
   if @choice.save
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to choices_path }
       format.json { head :no_content }
     end
   end
 end
```

In Rails Console, it outputs:

```
 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/choices
 Completed 302 Found in 58ms (ActiveRecord: 52.8ms)
```

Yet, the "new" page remains static.  Any idea on how to correctly redirect this, perhaps with a flash message saying "Images uploaded succesfully"?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Is it asynchronous request?

Comment: Yes, it is an asynchronous request.

Comment: Why is it asynchronous request, since you just want to do redirection?

Comment: I am uploading using jQuery File Upload

Comment: You can send javascript response and redirect user using javascript (`window.location.href = "url"` if I remember correctly. Still if I were you I would do this synchronously.

Comment: Also try to check similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078201/jquery-file-upload-rails-redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only just learnt what asynchronous requests are, so I hope this helps...

**If you're sending a 'background' request with JS, how can the controller affect your browser's viewport?**

The controller is *server-side*, and is loaded every time you send a request. This means that unless your actual browser made an HTTP request directly to the controller, how can it cause a change in the view you have already rendered?

JS is *client-side* technology, which means that it can cause things to happen *on your behalf*, but its scope is limited to taking "DOM" elements & interacting with them.

I looked at some pretty informative answers in this regard, and found these ideas:

- [Rails 3.2.0 - Redirecting after a JSON call is made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627862/rails-3-2-0-redirecting-after-a-json-call-is-made)
- [Rails 3: How to "redirect_to" in Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call)
- https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/206571

All of these answers say a similar thing: **you need to handle the redirect with JS**

Why not do something like this:

```
#app/controllers/choices_controller.rb
def create
 @choice = Choice.new(choice_params)
 @choice.filename = params[:filename].titleize
   if @choice.save
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to choices_path }
       format.json { render :json => {
          :location => url_for(:controller => 'choices', :action => 'index'),
          :flash => {:notice => "File Uploaded!"}
        }
     end
   end
 end

#assets/javascripts
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       success: function(data) {
           window.location = data.location
       }
    })
});
```

A much cleaner way to do it will be to send a plain JS request, and have this:

```
#/views/new.js.erb
window.location = <%= choices_path %>


#app/controllers/choices_controller.rb
def create
 @choice = Choice.new(choice_params)
 @choice.filename = params[:filename].titleize
   if @choice.save
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to choices_path }
       format.js
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

This i similar to the above answer, but a little more versatile. It took some playing but I finally got it working, and I signed up for StackOverflow just so I could post an answer. Here is my solution (though I was using JS as my format)

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to choices_path }
  @path = url_for(:controller => 'choices', :action => 'index')
  - or - choices_path for a named route
  format.js { render 'shared/redirect'}
  :flash => {:notice => "File Uploaded!"}
end
```

Now in your shared/redirect.js.erb file (notice this is a shared file, so you can reuse it):

```
#shared/redirect.js.erb
window.location.href = '<%= @path %>';
```